# Frameit always prints title/keyword in black even if another color is specified

Tags: continuous-integration, screenshot, fastlane

Frameit draws title and keyword in black even though I specified another colours for them. Here is my Framefile:

```
{
  "default": {
    "keyword": {
        "font": "../Fonts/SFCompactText-Heavy.otf",
        "color": "#76a43b"
    },
    "title": {
        "font": "../Fonts/SFCompactText-Regular.otf",
        "color": "#ffffff"
        },
    "background": "./background.jpg",
    "padding": 50,
    "stack_title" : true
  },
      "data": [
        {"filter":"Practice"},
        {"filter":"Mock"},
        {"filter":"PersonalTrainer"},
        {"filter":"Flag"}
      ]
}
```

Everything works well except for the colours. Could you please assist me?

I would also like to note that when I run frameit I get the following messages in the terminal:

> [17:52:58]: Framing screenshot
> './screenshots/motoTest/en-GB/iPhone7-Practice-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.png'
> gm composite: profile matches sRGB but writing iCCP instead
> (/var/folders/19/7_vlfd_122553vwlfsgwvvyh0000gn/T/mini_magick20170326-43271-kzqsz2.png). gm composite: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
> (/var/folders/19/7_vlfd_122553vwlfsgwvvyh0000gn/T/mini_magick20170326-43271-kzqsz2.png). gm identify: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
> (/var/folders/19/7_vlfd_122553vwlfsgwvvyh0000gn/T/mini_magick20170326-43271-wbze33.png). gm composite: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
> (/var/folders/19/7_vlfd_122553vwlfsgwvvyh0000gn/T/mini_magick20170326-43271-wbze33.png). gm convert: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
> (/var/folders/19/7_vlfd_122553vwlfsgwvvyh0000gn/T/mini_magick20170326-43271-8hnlgq.png).

## Update 1

I have now tried all possible alterations I could come up with:

1. Putting framefile in different locations
2. Specifying other fonts
3. Running frameit from the lane instead of directly from the terminal

None of these helped to resolve my issue.

## Update 2

For some strange reason even MindNote example doesn't work for me. The result is the same - all screenshots are black. So, I guess it is definitely not due to some mistake in my framefile...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what works for me, try this.

```
{
  "default": {
    "keyword": {
        "font": "../Fonts/SFCompactText-Heavy.otf",
        "color": "#76a43b"
    },
    "title": {
        "font": "../Fonts/SFCompactText-Regular.otf",
        "color": "#ffffff"
        },
    "background": "./background.jpg",
    "padding": 50,
    "stack_title" : true
  },
      "data": [
        {"filter":"Practice", "keyword": {"color": "#76a43b"}},
        {"filter":"Mock", "keyword": {"color": "#76a43b"}},
        {"filter":"PersonalTrainer", "keyword": {"color": "#76a43b"}},
        {"filter":"Flag", "keyword": {"color": "#76a43b"}}
      ]
}
```

I'm not sure at what point it is breaking for you, but for me it was failing to apply the color for the keyword only for one specific screenshot because my project had two Framefiles and I was editing the unused one. Just make sure that fastlane is using the framefile that is at the path where you are editing the framefile.

Hopefully you have figured out what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and found some old issues on Frameit Github. The solution they said was to use a non-white background, and it indeed worked if I use some fully green or pink background,  but as soon as the background was a bit white it stopped working again.

I finally got it working though by using the exact background.jpg file from the MindNode example. It's a bit grey but still looks okay to me.

See the MindNode example here:
https://github.com/fastlane/examples/tree/master/MindNode/screenshots